# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading ws), discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I make ping command in `discord.js`, but I got an error: `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ws')`. If you can help me, I will be very grateful, this is my code:

```
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");
const commandsHandler = require("../../Handlers/commands-handler");

module.exports = {
    name: "ping",
    aliases: ['latency', 'lag'],
    description: "Ping"
    
    execute(message, args, commandName, client, Discord) {
        const Response = new MessageEmbed()
        .setColor("BLUE")
        .setDescription(`${client.ws.ping}ms`);
        message.channel.send({embeds: [Response]});
    }
}
```

Comment: Can we see how you are calling the command as some times, the error might come due to a wrong order of the arguments you pass in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ws')

This means that `client` in `client.ws.ping` is `undefined`.

To prevent your program from crashing add a guard clause for client being `undefined` like this:

```
.setDescription(`${client?.ws?.ping || 'undefined'}ms`);
```

or at right before `const Response = new ...`, write this:

```
if (!client) return; // breaks out of function if `client` is `undefined`.
```

But you'll need to dig deeper to find out why `client` is coming in `undefined`.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer! When I follow your instructions there is indeed no error, but after typing the command I get a message: `undefinedms` instead ping of the bot, do you know why?

Comment: That’s because ‘client’ is undefined…